# pycurl.error: SSL unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, rest, ssl, https, pycurl

```
import pycurl
import certifi

c = pycurl.Curl()

c.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)

print(certifi.where())
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://XXXXX.com/api/asset/4615/maintenance/')

c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buf)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

The outupt is:

- Trying XX.XX.XX.XX ...
- Connected to XXXX port XXX (#0)
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem
  CApath: none
- SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
- Closing connection 0
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/automation/automation.py", line 27, in 
  c.perform()
  pycurl.error: (60, 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate')

I am currently trying to grab some information from a website using REST API, and it has SSL. And I added .cer SSL certificate of that appache website to the end of cacert.pem file, but still gives me this error. And I noticed that "CApath: none", but I dont know how to solve it. Any help would appreciate it.

Comment: Which is the output of `print(certifi.where())`?